# Python LoadLibrary not found

Tags: python, loadlibrary

I'm trying to load a .dll from Python. I am using Python 3.0.17114.1 with Visual Studio 2017 Preview. I get an error saying "NameError: name LoadLibrary is not defined".

Here is a code snip (note that theDll comes out perfect):

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library
from ctypes import LibraryLoader
from ctypes.util import find_library    
theDll = find_library('DsiLibrary_dll')
dsi_lib  = LoadLibrary(theDll)
```

So I read up on LoadLibrary and there are a few different ways to do it. I tried all I could find:

```
cdll.LoadLibrary(theDll)
CDLL.LoadLibrary(theDll)
ctypes.CDLL.LoadLibrary(theDll)
ctypes.LoadLibrary(theDll)
```

I'm very new at Python so I may have made some silly mistake. Can someone please make a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can access `LoadLibrary` like this:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import cdll 
from ctypes.util import find_library    
theDll = find_library('DsiLibrary_dll')
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(theDll)
# do stuff with lib
```

[Ctypes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html):

> On Linux, it is required to specify the filename including the
>   extension to load a library, so attribute access can not be used to
>   load libraries. Either the LoadLibrary() method of the dll loaders
>   should be used, or you should load the library by creating an instance
>   of CDLL by calling the constructor:
>
> ```
> >>> from ctypes import *
> >>> cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6") 
> <CDLL 'libc.so.6', handle ... at ...>
> >>> libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")       
> >>> libc
> <CDLL 'libc.so.6', handle ... at ...>
> >>>
> ```

Comment: I used your Windows method but that gives the same not defined error.

Comment: I did a cut and paste from your post. import ctypes
from ctypes import cdll 
from ctypes.util import find_library theDll = find_library('DsiLibrary_dll')
dsi_lib  = cdll.LoadLibrary(theDll)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "see it online". Are you talking about the snip you gave me? Maybe this is a bug in VS 2017 Preview Python. What Python are you using?

Comment: Yea, I see it online but it doesn't work on VS 2017 Preview Python. Maybe a bug.

Comment: Do you name your file ctypes.py? If not, it might be possible there's something wrong with your python...

Comment: Yes, my file is named PythonSample.py. But it is LoadLibrary that is not definec.

Comment: Here is a link to a screen shot of my cut/paste of your code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zu9j2thccxv0zvr/SO_Sample.png?dl=0

Comment: Your code isn't the same as my code, your code is the same as the code you posted in the question, not mine. Somehow there's a miss-copy/paste

Comment: I just did another copy/paste and now I get "OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application". Here is a correction: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zu9j2thccxv0zvr/SO_Sample.png?dl=0

Comment: i dont think that error is fixable with your current setup... http://stackoverflow.com/a/27910041/6622817

Comment: Ahh ... so you did fix my original problem. This is simply a 32/64 bit mixup. I'll work on that ... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Spent 2 days with the same problem on Win10 PC Using Python 3.10.2 x64.
Simple python code:

import os
import sys
import ctypes

aqui = os.getcwd()
print(aqui)
os.add_dll_directory(aqui)

if os.path.exists('LibFT260.dll'):
print('Found LibFT260.dll.')
else:
print('Failed to find LibFT260.dll.')
quit()

ft = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary('LibFT260.dll')

print(ft.FT260_GetChipVersion)

```
Error line:

> ft = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary('LibFT260.dll') with or w/o '.dll' suffix.
        
I put `LibFT260.dll` in the working directory (where I call the Python script) and the code adds that path to the os.add_dll_directory.  These were the 2
major fixes mentioned on the internet; neither worked.

[FYI:  The only ctypes library load statement that would work was 
ft = ctypes.WinDLL('LibFT260.dll', winmode = 1)
Microsoft LoadLibraryEx docs say not to use winmode = 1, it is only for backwards compatibility, so I changed to winmode = 48 which was suggested as one alternative.
(I never tried None, but 0 always failed, all other non-zero worked.)]

I ran the exact same program above on a 2nd PC and the LoadLibrary() function worked!

Details and the solution:
```

Machine 2 LoadLibrary() works
Lenovo P53s x64
Win10 21H2 build 19044.1526
Python 3.9.0 (x64)

Machine 1 LoadLibrary() doesn't work
Lenovo W530 x64
Win10 20H2 build 19042.1586
Python 3.10.2 (x64)
tried Python 3.9.0 (x64) still didn't work.

```
Then I noticed many Visual C++ differences between the machines.  
The P53s had a more Visual C++ versions installed.
When I matched those versions on the W530 the code above worked on Machine 1.

I don't know which versions I had and which I added new, but this list worked:
(I have both the x64 & the x86 versions of all listed below on Machine 1 now.)
```

Microsoft Visual Studio C++ Version 2005 Redistributable (MFC Security Update)
Version 2008                 (Ver 9.0.30729.6161)
Version 2010                 (Ver 10.0.40219)
Version 2013                 (Ver 12.0.40664)
Version 2015-2022            (Ver 14.31.31103)

```
All of these version were still available from Microsoft on March 16, 2022.
```