# python ctypes error "WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: python, c++, c, visual-studio-2013, ctypes

I have compiled a Windows 32bit DLL using Visual Studio 2013.
Name: Counter_order_sender.dll
Type: Debug

For Loading libraries I am using python ctypes library:
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('abs path to Counter_order_sender.dll')

This API is working perfectly fine on my PC (64bit OS, python 32bit)

However, when I am trying to run it on target machine with same configuration of OS and python version/architecture, I am getting following error:
"WindowsError:  [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

I have followed all the solutions related to the same question:

[Error loading DLL in python, not a valid win32 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849077/error-loading-dll-in-python-not-a-valid-win32-application)

=> where 64bit python and 32bit DLL was an issue. I even tried to build 64bit DLL and run it on my PC. I was able to reproduce the same error. However, 32bit DLL and 64bit DLL both were not working on target PC.

I have tried running dependency walker on my 32bit DLL. Here is the screenshot:
[image: Dependency walker screenshot]

I might be new with dependency walker application. Please help me figuring out, where I might be going wrong.

Comment: I have tried using 64bit WinDLL with 64bit python on target machine, it worked for me.

Comment: your target PC is XP?and what's your build type?try `x86`.