# How to fix OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError?

Tags: python, pyopenssl

I have a trouble about pyopenssl.
The error message is 'OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError'.

I'm debugging below.
https://github.com/opencv/open_model_zoo

First error happened.
asn1crypto._ffi.LibraryNotFoundError: The library libcrypto could not be found

I confirmed info below.

[where to get and install crypto.dll on 64 bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49302516/where-to-get-and-install-crypto-dll-on-64-bit-windows)

I changed from crypto to libcrypto in the file.

(virtualenv path)\Lib\site-packages\asn1crypto_perf_big_num_ctypes.py

So I resolved the first error.
But Second error happend.

OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError

My environment is below.
Windows 10
virtualenv
Python 3.7.1
pyopenssl 19.0.0
Visual C++ 2017
OpenSSL 1.0.2、1.1.0、1.1.1

(virtualenv path)\Lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py

1620 line

```
error = _lib.SSL_get_error(ssl, result)
if error == _lib.SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
    raise WantReadError()
I installed OpenSSL both of 1.0.2 and 1.1.1.
```

The error message is 'OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't know the reason, I executed it using no debug mode normally.