# Calling c++ in python using ctypes in windows

Tags: python, c++, windows, ctypes

I'm trying to speed up parts of my python code by calling c++ code using ctypes. I found many step-by-step guides, including some on this website. However, basically all of them assume linux operating systems and I am working with windows.

Based on some of the linux examples and some googling, I created the following MWE:

myfunc.cpp

```
extern "C" 
int timestwo(int mynum){
    return mynum*2;
}
```

I compile this with:

```
gcc -shared -o myfunc.dll myfunc.cpp
```

Then, I try to load the DLL file with python using:

usefunc.py

```
import ctypes
from os.path import abspath

dll = ctypes.CDLL(abspath('myfunc.dll'))
```

However, this gives the following error message:

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

**Edit:**
Solved. The problem was that I was generating a 32 bit DLL while using 64 BIT python. I re-installed MINGW64 with the following settings:

```
Architecture: x86_64
Threads: Win32
Exception: Seh
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: you can try building this code using VS code on windows, it will take care of the building process, then try to consume the .dll file.

Comment: As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27910041/3228591), is it possible that you're building a 64-bit DLL and loading it with 32-bit Python (or vice versa)?

Comment: @kemp: I use gcc.exe instead of mingw32-gcc.exe and when I start the python console it says: " [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32". So I think this should mean that both are 64 bit, but I'm definitely not sure.

Comment: You can use DUMPBIN to verify the bitness of your DLL. Once you have the bitness issues sorted out your DLL will have to actually export a symbol. Right now it doesn't. You'll probably want to use `__declspec(dllexport)` as the simplest way.

Comment: @IInspectable, Thank you for the comment. I ran it, and it said 32 bit word machine. So I guess it's not compiles as 64 bit. However, i downloaded the latest version of mingw-w64 and used that to compile. The results remains the same. Am I checking things correctly? If so, how can I compile as 64 bit? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using DUMPBIN is simple: `dumpbin /HEADERS myfunc.dll | findstr "machine"`. If that outputs that the binary is 32bits then that's the case. I'm not familiar with MinGW-w64, so I cannot help you there.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the help. It was the 32 bit, and I found out my mingw installation was wrong.