# Not valid win32 application when loading a dll file with ctypes

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I try to load a dll in the memory. I saw already different ways to do so. But none of these works for me. I tried:

```
LIB32_DLL = cdll.LoadLibrary("X:\direcory for the file\LIB32.dll")
```

And later I tried with:

```
LIB32_DLL = ctypes.WinDLL("X:\direcory for the file\LIB32.dll")
```

It also didn't work. I always get the same error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "X:/PycharmProjects/HHK52c/CallDesignFunction.py", line 18, in <module>
    LIB32_DLL = ctypes.WinDLL("X:\direcory for the file\LIB32.dll")
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 369, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: What is `LIB32.dll`?

Comment: It is a lib I got provided from a business partner. It is not a windows library

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27910041/6699447) will answer your question!